# Can't import MongoClient

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu, python-2.7

I am unable to do this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
```

I get:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name MongoClient
>>>
```

I am able to `import pymongo` without issues.

I am running `mongodb 2.2.3` and `Python 2.7`.

I've also tried this:

```
>>> connection = pymongo.MongoClient()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MongoClient'
>>>
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Did you install from PyPI or from git?

Comment: nope i dont even konw what that is

Comment: Did you install it with `pip install pymongo`, `easy_install pymongo`, or by downloading it and running `setup.py install`?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-pymongo

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That package is probably outdated or broken. Run `sudo apt-get purge python-pymongo`, then `sudo apt-get install python-pip`, then finally `sudo pip install pymongo`.

Answer (score 6):

According to [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient), `MongoClient` was introduced in version 2.4. As you installed `pymongo` from your distribution repository, it's quite possible it's not the most recent version. Try installing it via PiP (remove the one you have installed first):

```
pip install pymongo
```

Comment: thank you!! i actually had to install the older one because i could not get the most recent one to work!

Answer (score 4):

If you had named your script pymongo.py, which masks the pymongo module from which you are importing.

Rename your script to something else like xyz.py (and delete the pymongo.pyc file if one was created next to it).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest more robust answer:

```
pip show pymongo
```

now see where it direct you and from there simply remove the pymongo directory

```
rm -rf <the dir where pymongo lay>/pymongo*
```

Now, you can safely install pymongo again:

```
pip install pymongo
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem may occur if you have multiple .py programs in the current working directory.
Deleting them solved my error. I am not sure of the reason though.

Answer (score 1):

yes it's true you need to update use, check the upgrade section says http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html

```
   easy_install -U pymongo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used pymongo.Connection and encountered error, you should know that after the new updates, you should use pymongo.MongoClient instead.  I had this issue so hopefully this will be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

**Python Script**

Try it once, into python script run following statement

```
# try.py

import pymongo
```

If above statement didn't throw any exception then you need to install `pymongo-2.4`, if existing `pymongo` verion is `2.3`

**Open terminal**

First you need to uninstall old `pymongo` version

```
pip uninstall pymongo
```

Then use following commands to install `pymongo-2.4`

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pymongo/pymongo-2.4.tar.gz
tar xzf pymongo-2.4.tar.gz
cd pymongo-2.4
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04.
This solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev

sudo apt-get install python-pip

sudo pip install pymongo
```

Comment: some explanation about what you are doing there please?

Comment: The build-essentials reference all the packages needed to compile the python-dev tools. Then install pip and install pymongo with pip. If you already have pymongo installed, you can purge pymongo and then install pymongo package in the above way. PS - I did not check it in other versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me for conda env

```
pip uninstall pymongo
```

then

```
pip install pymongo
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your python source file is not called pymongo.py

Comment: This question was originally asked 7 years ago with 10 other answers?

Answer (score 0):

Change filename from pymongo.py to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You have a file named queue.py in your project folder.  Rename that file, and that should fix the problem.

Comment: Please explain the reason of conflict too.

Answer (score 0):

For newer version of pymongo, you don't need to import MongoClient. Do the following:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.test_database
db.test_table
```

You'll get:

```
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'test_database'), 'test_table')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `mypy` type checks for the `MongoClient` class of `pymongo`. This solved the issue:

```
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a virtual environment using Python 3.11 as the library has some changes which will not work with this code.

Secondly, along with `pymongo`, install `pymongo[srv]` then try to run the code. I hope it will work now.

To create conda environment:

```
conda create venv python==3.9 -y
```

To activate environment:

```
conda activate venv
```

Then to install the required packages:

```
pip install pymongo

pip install pymongo[srv]
```