# Connection to pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I am trying to connect to mongo in MAC using pymongo. I am getting the following error-

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       from pymongo import MongoClient
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'MongoClient'

I have tried Connection also. But it gives the same error. Any help?

Comment: It would have been better to show the code, but you should have `from pymongo import MongoClient` which seems to be the line that is wrong.

Comment: Can you check if your problem could be found here: [MongoClient import error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624416/cant-import-mongoclient)

Comment: As per above comments it is difficult to point out exact cause of the problem without more context. Can you check what python installation you are using ? e.g. if you have both python26 and python27 it will depend on for which python version you have installed pymongo for. You can also elaborate on how you installed the pymongo.

Comment: try pip freeze to check if pymongo is installed..

Answer (score 0):

Steps for troubleshooting:

1. First of all, verify if your environment is activated and you are in the correct environment.
2. If it is active and you're in the correct environment, then verify if you have installed pymongo.
3. If it's not installed in your environment, install it using `pip install pymongo` in the environment you want to work.